# Can I add DLC after I've started the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I got the Collector's edition for PS3 and thought "From Ashes" came with the 54MB online pass activation.  Now it seems I need to add it and redeem a second code.  I started my game already so I'm wondering if I download the add-on now will I need to start over to play it? Or will it show up during the game even though I've started?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**. You can install the DLC after starting a game and still access the content. After installing the "From Ashes" DLC, look for the mission called Priority: Eden Prime. The mission will be available to you in the game as soon as you board the Normandy and can use your Galaxy Map.

[Official EA support page:](https://help.ea.com/article/mass-effect-3-from-ashes-dlc-info)

> You will know you have the content, as you will get an email in your
>   private terminal as a priority request from Eden Prime.